# how can i find out the version of SQL express installed on my machine?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express

Experts

is there a way to find out the version of SQL express installed on my machine?

Comment: Open it?  And go to help > about?

Comment: @Tom: that will show you the version of management studio, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Connect to it using [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en) (or some other sql client) and run:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

This will give you detailed information about the version you are connected to. An example from my installation:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)
Jul 9 2008 14:17:44
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6001: Service Pack 1)
```

Comment: thanks, i also need to know what is "R2" and how to find out if my SQL2008 is R2 or not?

Comment: @mokokamello: R2 is a version of SQL Server, just like 2000, 2005, 2008, etc... (it is Release 2 of SQL Server 2008). You will know you have R2 because it will say "Microsoft SQL Server ... R2" in the output of the above query.